# how to pass a object inside the logger.log() file in winston@3.0.0 in nodejs

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

i have a http request in a variable `queryData = qs.parse(requestBody);`
when i try to parse through winston

```
logger.log("info","requestbody",+queryData);
```

even tried

```
logger.log("info","requestbody %s", queryData);
logger.log("info","requestbody",{queryData});
```

didn't worked

am getting error like:

```
{ TypeError:    Cannot create property 'Symbol(level)' on string 'Registering Device typeac'
    at DerivedLogger.log (/home/grl/www/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:130:20)
    at createOcfRes (/home/aol/www/iot-node-server.js:285:10)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/aol/www/iot-node-server.js:115:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:186:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9) level: 'error', timestamp: '19-07-2018 20:20:19' }
```

Comment: You error message does not fit your code snippets. In those three code snippets you are passing three arguments to `logger.log`, but according to the [code](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/e5dabef5c556b523b3c9a239bacc6c4ef3cca38d/lib/winston/logger.js#L130) referenced in the stack trace, this specific error happened when there was only one argument.

Comment: @LucasS. yes for winston.logger.log()  takes 3 param, anyways thanks i got the solution for this. I just converted the object to json.stringify and then i passed to logger